# How WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control is supposed to work?

Tags: theme-customizer, custom-background

I'm trying to add a second background image function to my theme customizer with this code.

```
    // HTML Background Image
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'html_background_image', 
    array(
        'capability'     => 'edit_theme_options',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 
    new WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'background_image', 
        array(
            'label'    => __('HTML Background Image', 'TEXTDOMAIN'),
            'section'  => 'background_image',
            'settings' => 'html_background_image',
)));
```

But it doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have this code hooked to the `customize_register` action? Is it contained inside a function?

Comment: Yes, everything else works fine.

Comment: What does `var_dump (get_theme_mod( 'background_image'));` show

Comment: It shows: string(0) ""

Answer (score 2):

There's very little documentation on this class, but here below is the full example from WordPress [core](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L808) (here's [github](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L808)). Note you'd be using the `$wp_customize` object you get as argument to your `custom_register` callback and not `$this` as does the core class. I've done a search and replace below and it works.

```
        /* CORE COPY PASTE */
        //https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L808

        /* Custom Background */

        $wp_customize->add_section( 'background_image', array(
            'title'          => __( 'Background Image' ),
            'theme_supports' => 'custom-background',
            'priority'       => 80,
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'background_image', array(
            'default'        => get_theme_support( 'custom-background', 'default-image' ),
            'theme_supports' => 'custom-background',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( new WP_Customize_Background_Image_Setting( $wp_customize, 'background_image_thumb', array(
            'theme_supports' => 'custom-background',
        ) ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control( $wp_customize ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'background_repeat', array(
            'default'        => 'repeat',
            'theme_supports' => 'custom-background',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'background_repeat', array(
            'label'      => __( 'Background Repeat' ),
            'section'    => 'background_image',
            'type'       => 'radio',
            'choices'    => array(
                'no-repeat'  => __('No Repeat'),
                'repeat'     => __('Tile'),
                'repeat-x'   => __('Tile Horizontally'),
                'repeat-y'   => __('Tile Vertically'),
            ),
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'background_position_x', array(
            'default'        => 'left',
            'theme_supports' => 'custom-background',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'background_position_x', array(
            'label'      => __( 'Background Position' ),
            'section'    => 'background_image',
            'type'       => 'radio',
            'choices'    => array(
                'left'       => __('Left'),
                'center'     => __('Center'),
                'right'      => __('Right'),
            ),
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_setting( 'background_attachment', array(
            'default'        => 'fixed',
            'theme_supports' => 'custom-background',
        ) );

        $wp_customize->add_control( 'background_attachment', array(
            'label'      => __( 'Background Attachment' ),
            'section'    => 'background_image',
            'type'       => 'radio',
            'choices'    => array(
                'fixed'      => __('Fixed'),
                'scroll'     => __('Scroll'),
            ),
        ) );
```

It appears you cannot customize the e.g. section, and for evidence look to this code for the third argument to [WP_Customize_Image_Control](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php#L654)